# How to modify this code to set different colours for horizontal lines?

Tags: python

I would like to set the horizontal colour to be black if it is for isUp and blue if it is for isDown.

```
levels = []
for i in range(2,df.shape[0]-2):
  if isUp(df,i):
    levels.append((i,df['low'][i]))
  elif isDown(df,i):
    levels.append((i,df['high'][i]))

for level in levels:
    plt.hlines(level[1],xmin=df['date'][level[0]],xmax=max(df['date']),colors='blue')
plt.show()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set different colors in the first `for` loop only while checking **isUp** or **isDown** conditions:

```
for i in range(2,df.shape[0]-2):
    if isUp(df,i):
        plt.hlines(df['low'][i],xmin=df['date'][i],xmax=max(df['date']),colors='black')
    elif isDown(df,i):
        plt.hlines(df['high'][i],xmin=df['date'][i],xmax=max(df['date']),colors='blue')

plt.show()
```